# Iphone App Memory leak due to UIKeyboardInputManager

Tags: iphone, ios

Memory leaks occurred in my app due to UIKeyboardInputManager. How can i solve ? please help me

Comment: You can solve it by providing some context...

Comment: Did you "build and analyze" your code with xcode ? That will show you where your leak come from. You should also copy and paste your code here.

Comment: please, provide more info: how did you detect the leak (interments? static analyzer?)? any useful traces, bits of code?

Comment: @sergio: In analyzer no problem. this problem is in instruments. when i enter text in to uitextfield

Comment: Are you using the simulator or the device? Are you implementing a UITextFieldDelegate? could the problem be there?

Comment: @sergio: i'm using simulator. Not implemented UITextFieldDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the simulator, don´t worry. It is not a good indicator of how memory would work on a real device. Repeat your test with a real device.

Furthermore, it seems [there is a bug with `UITextField` memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691528/uitextfield-memory-leak).